# Rails render lookup value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, lookup

First: Enter a certain emp_no using the textfield.
Second: I am trying to render/show the lookup value from a table through .

Here's the view:

```
  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :emp_no %><br />
   <%= f.text_field :emp_no%>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
   <%= f.label :emp_name %><br />
   <div><label><%= @emp_name %></label></div>
  </div>
```

Here's my controller:

```
  before_filter :customer

  def customer
   @emp_name = where(Employee.params[:employee_code])
  end
```

Any inputs are much appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You're going to need to use ajax to post the emp_no and have a controller action that returns the name

Comment: I'll check on that one. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We've achieved something similar at http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk (try the search at the top)

---

**Search**

What you're looking for, simply, is a piece of functionality which helps you *search* your data.

This can be achieved relatively simply, but you have to make sure your syntax is correct:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :employees do
   get :search
end

#app/controllers/employees_controller.rb
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
   layout: Proc.new {|controller| controller.request.xhr? ? false : "application" }

   def search
      @emp_names = Employee.where code: params[:employee_code]
   end
end

#app/views/employees/search.html.erb
<% @emp_names.each do |employee| %>
  <%= employee.name %>
<% end %>
```

This setup will provide you with the ability to load the `search` items *if* you wanted to show them, allowing you both the ability to use `ajax` (detailed below), or just plain HTML / HTTP

---

**Ajax**

If you wanted to use Ajax to deliver "real time" results, you'll want to use the following details:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(document).on("ajax:success", "form", function(status, data, xhr){
    $(this).append(data);
});
```

This *should* render the results wherever you want on your front-end (requesting) page. The trick lies in the controller's assertion of the `layout` depending on the type of request received (HTTP or XHR)

---

**Form**

Finally, your *form* needs to reflect the functionality you wish to define. Currently, you don't have any way to send the request to your `emp_names` method, and so you need to create a better way to manage it:

```
#view
<%= form_tag employees_search_path, remote: true do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :input %>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

Of course, the form can change considerably, but it basically means that you will send a simple request to your `employees_search_path`, which will then give you the capacity to manage the response in the controller; either normally, or with Ajax

Comment: Thank you for this detailed explanation. I'm just starting with ruby on rails and needs to look on different ways to do things within it. Thanks again! :)

Comment: No problem! Please keep me updated about whether it helps you!